# Custom Logging in Jetty11

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty

I am implementing Custom logging in Jetty11. My use case is to add custom attributes while logging. It is the follow-up question for
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68737248/how-to-override-request-logging-mechanism-in-jetty-11-0-6)

I have written a custom class 'MyJettyLogger' mentioned below that extends CustomRequestLog

```
package com.ashish.Jetty.customLoggerImplementation;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.CustomRequestLog;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response;

public class MyJettyLogger extends CustomRequestLog
{
    @Override
    public void log(Request request, Response response)
    {
        super.log(request, response);
    }

    public MyJettyLogger(Writer writer, String logStr)
    {
        super(writer, setCustomAttributesToLog(logStr));
    }

    private static String setCustomAttributesToLog(String logStr){

        StringBuilder logBuffer = new StringBuilder(logStr);
        logBuffer.append(" ");
        logBuffer.append(1234);
        logBuffer.append(" ");
        logBuffer.append("Ashishs");
        logBuffer.append(" ");
        logBuffer.append("");
        logBuffer.append(" dcn");

        return logBuffer.toString() ;
    }

}
```

I have also copied **${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-requestlog.xml** to **${jetty.base}/etc/jetty-requestlog.xml** and  replaced **'com.ashish.Jetty.customLoggerImplementation.MyJettyLogger'** instead of **'org.eclipse.jetty.server.CustomRequestLog'** as mentioned below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_10_0.dtd">

<!-- =============================================================== -->
<!-- Configure the Jetty Request Log                                 -->
<!-- =============================================================== -->
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <!-- Configure Request Log for Server                            -->
  <!-- (Use RequestLogHandler for a context specific RequestLog    -->
  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <Set name="RequestLog">
    <New id="RequestLog" class="com.ashish.Jetty.customLoggerImplementation.MyJettyLogger">
      <!-- Writer -->
      <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncRequestLogWriter">
          <Arg>
            <Call name="resolvePath" class="org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration">
              <Arg><Property name="jetty.base"/></Arg>
              <Arg>
                <Property name="jetty.requestlog.filePath">
                  <Default>
                    <Property name="jetty.requestlog.dir" default="logs"/>/yyyy_mm_dd.request.log
                  </Default>
                </Property>
              </Arg>
            </Call>
          </Arg>

          <Set name="filenameDateFormat"><Property name="jetty.requestlog.filenameDateFormat" default="yyyy_MM_dd"/></Set>
          <Set name="retainDays"><Property name="jetty.requestlog.retainDays" default="90"/></Set>
          <Set name="append"><Property name="jetty.requestlog.append" default="false"/></Set>
          <Set name="timeZone"><Property name="jetty.requestlog.timezone" default="GMT"/></Set>
        </New>
      </Arg>

      <!-- Format String -->
      <Arg>
        <Property name="jetty.requestlog.formatString" deprecated="jetty.customrequestlog.formatString">
          <Default>
            <Get class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.CustomRequestLog" name="EXTENDED_NCSA_FORMAT"/>
          </Default>
        </Property>
      </Arg>
    </New>
  </Set>
</Configure>
```

I am testing this via Jetty stand alone server using  deployed war and getting below error while starting Jetty.
I

```
2021-08-13 10:20:46.757:WARN :oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Unable to execute XmlConfiguration
java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ashish.Jetty.customLoggerImplementation.MyJettyLogger 
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:558)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1810)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:226)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:502)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:73)
```

It might be possible that I am doing couple of mistakes here as I am exploring Jetty11.
Please help.

Comment: Does `--list-config` show your jar file is loaded by the server?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt No,  I am deploying war files in webapps. It's fine I will deploy the .class file directly. Just wanted to make sure of the complete approach: are these correct changes in ${jetty.base}/etc/jetty-requestlog.xml ?

Comment: The server needs access to your new `MyJettyLogger` class, as RequestLog is done at the server level, not the webapp, so that needs to be packaged in a jar that the server can access.